# Plot not updaing correctly using draw() (duplicated axes) in wxPython

Tags: python, plot, wxwidgets, axes

I am new to Python and wxPython I am trying to simulate particles in a box with random velocities in random directions.
I created a simple GUI in wxFormBuilder where I have a panel to show a plot of the paricles. The particles are set to a position and plotted onto the panel, then I start the simulation and update the x and y positons of the particles. When redrawing the positions The axes appear 'thicker' as before, it looks like if there are several axes ontop of eachother.

I cant find anything about this problem, I hope somebody could help me with this?

This is the code that creates the Plot:

```
import wx
import particles


import random
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import \
        FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigCanvas, \
        NavigationToolbar2WxAgg as NavigationToolbar
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 8})

class MyFrameSub( particles.GUI_MainFrame ):
    def __init__( self, parent ):
        particles.GUI_MainFrame.__init__( self, parent )

    def InitData(self):
        self.npart = int(self.m_npart.GetValue())
        self.nsteps = int(self.m_steps.GetValue())
        self.ndt = float(self.m_dt.GetValue())

        self.x= [random.random() for I in range(self.npart)]
        self.y= [2*random.random()-1 for I in range(self.npart)]
        self.vx= [self.ndt*(2*random.random()-1) for I in range(self.npart)]
        self.vy= [self.ndt*(2*random.random()-1) for I in range(self.npart)]
        return

    def CreatePlot(self):
        panelsize = self.m_PlotPanel.GetClientSize()
        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(panelsize[0]/100.0,panelsize[1]/100.0), dpi=100, frameon=False)

        self.canvas = FigCanvas(self.m_PlotPanel, wx.ID_ANY, self.figure)

        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.axes.axis((-1,1,-1,1))

        self.partplot, = self.axes.plot(self.x, self.y, 'ro')

        self.canvas.draw()
        return

    def UpdateData(self):
        for i in range(self.nsteps):
            for j in range(self.npart):
                self.x[j]=self.x[j]+self.vx[j]
                self.y[j]=self.y[j]+self.vy[j]

                if abs(self.x[j])>1:
                    self.vx[j]=-self.vx[j]
                if abs(self.y[j])>1:
                    self.vy[j]=-self.vy[j]

            self.partplot.set_xdata(self.x)
            self.partplot.set_ydata(self.y)
            self.canvas.draw()
        return
```

followed by the button definitions, it looks like this:
Before running the simulation: [www.merlinvs.de/before.jpg](http://www.merlinvs.de/before.jpg)

[image]

and after running the simulation: [www.merlinvs.de/after.jpg](http://www.merlinvs.de/after.jpg)

[image]

As you see the axes got ugly and I have no idea why.

Another question I was thinking about is the following:
When I run a loop that takes a while the UI is unresponsive, is it possible to have the UI active to cancel a loop if desired?

Comment: The solution to the problem mentioned above is described on the following pages:

[Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286731/animating-matplotlib-panel-blit-leaves-old-frames-behind)

[Link2](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Animations)

especially the second link provides detailed Information.

I dont know how to close this question, as I'm not allowed to accept an Answer I have written myself.

Answer (score 0):

As for the unresponsive UI, I used greenlets for my Matplotlib stuff while updating it

```
from gevent.greenlet import Greenlet
from gevent import sleep
import matplotlib.plot as plt

# Plot stuff

def event_handler():
  # Can update plot
  sleep(1) # Simulate handling or number crunching (numpy WILL block)

g = Greenlet(event_handler)
g.start()
plt.plot(0,0) # Works immediately and updates
```

Some things of note is that for serious applications you need to add some protection against race coditions with the plot.  Numpy and external science libraries typically cause the entire application to become unresponsive (in my experience) because they are blocking system calls outside of the greenlet context switcher's reach.  For something simple though the above pattern works well.

Comment: Thank you for pointing to greenlets, this looks very interesting. I will read up on this as I don't understand all of thist yet.

Comment: Greenlets are thread-like tasklets that are sequenced and switched in the python instance. Because of Python's global interpreter lock threads are inefficient so Greenlets step in and control context switching and provide a very clean API for using concurrency, in this case one for your plot and one for your event loop (listening for user actions).