# How modules know each other

Tags: python, python-2.7

I can plot data from a CSV file with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('test0.csv',delimiter='; ', engine='python')
df.plot(x='Column1', y='Column3')
plt.show()
```

But I don't understand one thing. How `plt.show()` knows about `df`? I'll make more sense to me seeing, somewhere, an expression like:

```
plt = something(df)
```

I have to mention I'm just learning Python.

Comment: Basically `df` also imports `plt` and modifies it directly. `plt` uses a lot of global state which is accessible to users and code alike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the pandas docs on [plotting](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/cebc70cc277462176edea73bb71eaad9f83e9f47/doc/source/visualization.rst#basic-plotting-plot):

> The `plot` method on Series and DataFrame is just a simple wrapper
>   around :meth:`plt.plot() <matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot>`

So as is, the `df.plot` method is an highlevel call to `plt.plot` (using a *wrapper*), and thereafter, calling [`plt.show`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L240) will simply:

> display all figures and block until the figures have been closed

as it would with for all figures plotted with `plt.plot`.

---

Therefore, you don't see `plt = something(df)` as you would expect, because `matpotlib.pyplot.plot` is being called *behind the scene* by `df.plot`.

Comment: I got it. But I would like to ask, is there someway to write the code so that magic becomes more explicit?

Comment: @KcFnMi I don't think you need the explicit magic. That wrapper saves us the trouble of passing the required args and kwargs to `plt.plot` as required for sometimes complicated dataframes.

Answer (score 3):

Matplotlib has two "interfaces": a [Matlab-style interface](http://jakevdp.github.io/mpl_tutorial/tutorial_pages/tut1.html) and an [object-oriented interface](http://jakevdp.github.io/mpl_tutorial/tutorial_pages/tut2.html).

Plotting with the Matlab-style interface looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

The call to `plt.plot` implicitly creates a figure and an axes on which to draw.
The call to `plt.show` displays all figures.

Pandas is supporting the Matlab-style interface by implicitly creating a figure and axes for you when `df.plot(x='Column1', y='Column3')` is called.

Pandas can also use the more flexible object-oriented interface, in which case
your code would look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('test0.csv',delimiter='; ', engine='python')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(ax=ax, x='Column1', y='Column3')
plt.show()
```

Here the axes, `ax`, is explicitly created and passed to `df.plot`, which then
calls `ax.plot` under the hood.

One case where the object-oriented interface is useful is when you wish to use
`df.plot` more than once while still drawing on the same axes:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(ax=ax, x='Column1', y='Column3')
df2.plot(ax=ax, x='Column2', y='Column4')
plt.show()
```

Comment: What's the meaning of `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`? I was expecting just one thing at the left side.

Comment: The figure is responsible for the entire image displayed. The axes is responsible for a plotting area. A figure can contain many axes. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14846126/190597 for more on how matplotlib's object hierarchy is organized.

Comment: @KcFnMi `plt.subplots` returns two objects, which can either be assigned to one name to create a tuple, or assigned to two names separately.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.show , the `plt.show()` itself doesn't know about the data, you need to pass the data as parameters.

What you are seeing should be the plot of pandas library, according to the usage http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#basic-plotting-plot.

Hope this solves your question.