# Matplotlib cannot draw all the subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw 7 or 8 Histogram (share x axis) dynamically in one figure using Python. But the figure only show part of it.
[image]
Although it has 7 subplots:
[image]
Here is my codes:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import pickle
distribution = pickle.load(open("data.txt", "r"))
fig,axes = plt.subplots(nrows = len(distribution), sharex = True)
index=0
for tag in distribution_progress:
    axes[index].hist(distribution_[tag],bins=50, normed=1, facecolor='yellowgreen', alpha=0.75)
    axes[index].set_title(tag)
    index += 1
plt. subplots_adjust( top = 3, hspace = 0.4)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm confused. What is the problem? Which graph is produced?

Comment: `top = 3` means that the content of the figure is 300% larger than the figure itself. Hence only its bottom part is shown. The second picture seems to be the desired outcome so it's unclear what the question really is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a figure size with a larger height/width ratio:

```
width, height = 6, 8
fig,axes = plt.subplots(nrows=N, sharex=True, figsize=(width, height))
```

Increase the [`hspace`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html) to provide enough room for the subplot titles:

```
plt. subplots_adjust(hspace = 1.0)
```

As [ImportanceOfBeingErnest pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48262442/matplotlib-cannot-draw-all-the-subplots#comment83508043_48262442), don't use `top = 3` since that places the top of the subplots at y = 3 in the [Figure coordinate system](https://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html), whereas the top of the visible figure is always at y = 1 (in the Figure coordinate system).

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N = 8
width, height = 6, 8
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=N, sharex=True, figsize=(width, height))
index = 0
for tag in range(N):
    axes[index].hist(np.random.random(100), bins=50, normed=1,
                     facecolor='yellowgreen', alpha=0.75)
    axes[index].set_title(tag)
    index += 1
plt. subplots_adjust(hspace=1.0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If I understand correctly, the subplots share the figure, and the figure's max size is limited. So I cannot enlarge the height of each of the 7 charts, otherwise it is exceeded the boundary of figure?

Comment: @PingjiangLi: Yes, that's basically right. [`plt.subplots_adjust`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html) changes spacing parameters. It does not enlarge axes. It only changes their position within the figure. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14846126/190597) for more on matplotlib's hierarchy of objects.